# Cordova 4 and Ripple

Tags: cordova, ripple, cordova-4

I have a problem emulating my applications in cordova. I have found ripple when it was still Cordova 3 but since the update to Cordova 4 ripple seems not working. With this problem at hand and a very low specs device, I would like to ask for recommendation of emulator that I could use, Or is it just me that don't know how to make ripple work with Cordova 4?

Comment: AFAIK, ripple is broken on chrome 46, not a cordova issue. You should try genymotion

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will consider genymotion